# scrapy get data dict from json dictionary

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to get all of the data stored in this json

[image]

as a dictionary that I can load and access. I am still new to writing spiders, but I believe I need something like
response.xpath().extract()
and then json.load().split() to get an element from it.
But the exact syntax I am not sure of, since there are so many elements in this file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, it pretty much works like you suggested in your question.
You can check the script tags for 'windows.PAGE_MODEL' with a simple xpath query.
Please try the following code in the callback for your request:

```py
d = response.xpath('//script[text()[contains(., "windows.PAGE_MODEL")]]/text()').get()
from json import loads
data = loads(d)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `re_first()` to extract JSON from JavaScript code and next `loads()` it using `json` module:

```
import json
d = response.xpath('//script[contains(., "windows.PAGE_MODEL")]/text()').re_first(r'(?s)windows.PAGE_MODEL = (.+?\});')
data = json.loads(d)
property_id = data['propertyData']['id']
```